# Zoom to extent of ajax-loaded vector layer in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers

I'm loading GeoJSON-data as result from a query to a PostGis-database via AJAX. The feature show up on the map, but I cannot get my map to center on the loaded feature.

```
var myLayer = new ol.layer.Vector ... // from returned GeoJSON

searchResults.setLayers(new ol.Collection([myLayer]));  // add the layer to a layergroup which is already bound to the map
myLayer.setVisible(true);  // the layer shows up keeping the initial mapview
var extent=parzellen.getSource().getExtent();
alert (extent);  // at this point alert shows me Infinity,Infinity,-Infinity,-Infinity
map.getView().fit(extent, map.getSize());  // this never happens
```

As shown in the code, propbably due to the fact, that myLayer is called via AJAX the code is executed before the source is completely loaded. Therefore alert(extent) returns Infinity,...

I found, that I have to wait until the source is ready. But in my case this isn't working and the layer doesn't show anymore on the map?

```
   myLayer.on('change',function(e){
      if(myLayer.getSource().getState() === 'ready') {
        if(myLayer.getSource().getFeatures().length>0) {
          searchResults.setLayers(new ol.Collection([myLayer]));
          myLayer.setVisible(true); 
          map.getView().fit(myLayer.getSource().getExtent(), map.getSize());
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following solution [here in a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27226528/alert-changes-functionality-of-ol3-zoom) :

```
parzellen.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    map.getView().fit(parzellen.getSource().getExtent(), (map.getSize()));
});
```

This did the trick.

Without knowing why in all other cases parzellen.getSource().getExtent() returned Infinity,.. ?